# How to append the variable to linux command and then execute the final linux command($cmd: qic-run -t /mnt/etc/ -d 1000) using ksh

Tags: shell, sh, ksh

teststr="-t /mnt/etc/ -d 1000"

echo $teststr

cmd="qic-run $teststr"

echo $cmd

qic-run -t /mnt/etc/ -d 1000

Answer (score 0):

For a single/simple command:

```
args=(-t /mnt/etc/ -d 1000)
qic-run "${args[@]}"
```

Comment: Actually, if I execute just 'args' part, it gives the following issue:
args=(-t /mnt/etc/ -d 1000)
ksh: syntax error: `(' unexpected

Comment: @BhawneetSingh Does it work if you run `typeset -a args` first? Sorry I don't have ksh right now to test. ksh does support arrays.

Comment: Another way to to store commands is a function: `qr () { qic-run -t /mnt/etc/ -d 1000; }`.

Comment: typeset -a args doesn't work in ksh too. Thank you.

Comment: What version of ksh are you using?